# How to call a external function inside a Web Worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm learning about Web Worker and today I needed make a external function work inside a Web Worker like this:

main.js:

```js
function doSomething(parameter){
   //Doing something
}
if (window.Worker) {
   const myWorker = new Worker("worker.js");
   myWorker.postMessage("Hello World");
} else {
   console.log('Your browser doesn\'t support web workers.');
}
```

worker.js:

```js
onmessage = function(e) {
   doSomething(e.data)
}
```

Have a way to do this work?

Answer (score 2):

Everything you send to a web worker has to be **serializable**. As a function is not, you can't use the callback pattern as you probably would like to do.

The only solution is to send a message back to the main thread just like you did with `postMessage`, and the main thread has to acknowledge that message with the `message` event listener and execute the `doSomething` function on its own.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky, but depending on your use case, you can do something like the following:

```js
// main.js

const doSomething = (param) => {
   return param + '!!!'
}

const worker = new Worker("worker.js")

worker.postMessage({
    fn: doSomething.toString(),
    param: "Hello World",
})

worker.onmessage = (e) => {
    console.log(e.data) // logs "Hello World!!!"
}

// worker.js:

self.onmessage = (e) => {
    const { fn, param } = e.data

    const result = eval(`(${fn})`)(param)

    self.postMessage(result)
}
```

Note that `eval` is generally best avoided, but it can be safe here as long as `doSomething` is trusted code.

Note also that this will fail if `doSomething` relies on dependencies external to itself; all such dependencies will need to be serializable and passed explicitly as parameters, via the same `postMessage` mechanism.

Comment: I tried do this in my sample and this error it happened
: eval(....) is not a function

Comment: @BrunoLeo my bad, it needs parens to make it work with function declarations as well as function expressions. I've edited the answer